# Solr LTR query not working even though the model and feature store is present?

Tags: solr

I have configured LTR in my solr collection and I am able to see my feature and model file. To test things out I have kept only two features and a very basic model file. I have attached both the files.
I am able to retrieve the features using the following query :

> localhost:8983/solr/waterstest/query?q=*:*&fl=title,id,description,score,[features
> store=myWatersFeatureStore efi.boostedTitle=columns
> efi.boostedDescription=Heater]

The above works fine. I am able to retrieve the feature and the score with the data

The problem comes when I try to rerank the results with the uploaded model. Here are the queries I have tried to rerank the results

> localhost:8983/solr/waterstest/query?q=title:columns&rq={!ltr
> model=myWatersModel reRankDocs=100 efi.boostedTitle=columns
> efi.boostedDescription=Heater}&fl=id,score

```
Response

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":400,
    "QTime":28,
    "params":{
      "q":"title:columns",
      "fl":"id,score",
      "rq":"{!ltr model=myWatersModel reRankDocs=100 efi.boostedTitle=columns efi.boostedDescription=Heater}"}},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException"],
    "msg":"Error from server at null: cannot find model myWatersModel",
    "code":400}}
```

There is nothing in logs just the same error there

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: cannot find model myWatersModel
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.processErrorsAndResponse(Http2SolrClient.java:742)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.request(Http2SolrClient.java:412)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.request(Http2SolrClient.java:761)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1290)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler.request(HttpShardHandler.java:78)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardRequestor.call(ShardRequestor.java:130)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardRequestor.call(ShardRequestor.java:41)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:180)
        at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:212)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am able to retrieve the model store also :

> localhost:8983/solr/waterstest/schema/model-store

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1},
  "models":[{
      "name":"myWatersModel",
      "class":"org.apache.solr.ltr.model.LinearModel",
      "store":"myWatersFeatureStore",
      "features":[{
          "name":"isboostedTitle",
          "norm":{"class":"org.apache.solr.ltr.norm.IdentityNormalizer"}},
        {
          "name":"isboostedDescription",
          "norm":{"class":"org.apache.solr.ltr.norm.IdentityNormalizer"}}],
      "params":{"weights":{
          "isboostedTitle":0.4,
          "isboostedDescription":0.2}}}]}
```

If the feature query works and I am able to retrieve the model as well then why am I getting the model null error. I know the error handling part is not apt here so can someone help me to point out what all could have gone wrong here?

This is how the feature file looks like

```
[
  {
    "store" : "myWatersFeatureStore",
    "name" : "isboostedTitle",
    "class" : "org.apache.solr.ltr.feature.SolrFeature",
    "params" : { "q" :"{!field f=title}${boostedTitle}"  }
  },
  {
    "store" : "myWatersFeatureStore",
    "name" : "isboostedDescription",
    "class" : "org.apache.solr.ltr.feature.SolrFeature",
    "params" : { "q" :"{!field f=description}${boostedDescription}" }
  }
]
```

And the corresponding model file

```
{
  "store" : "myWatersFeatureStore",
  "name" : "myWatersModel",
  "class" : "org.apache.solr.ltr.model.LinearModel",
  "features" : [
    { "name" : "isboostedTitle" },
    { "name" : "isboostedDescription" }
  ],
  "params" : {
    "weights" : {
      "isboostedTitle" : 0.4,
      "isboostedDescription" : 0.2
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using? Have you reloaded the collection after uploading the feature store and the model? Could you please share the solrconfig.xml?

Comment: Using solr version 8.6. the following query worked localhost:8983/solr/waterstest/query?q=title:columns&rq={!ltr model=myWatersModel reRankDocs=100 efi.boostedTitle=columns efi.boostedDescription=Heater}&fl=id,score,[feature] . collection reload was required after adding the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comments section a collection reload was required becuase testing the same thing on a single core on techproducts worked however in case of collection a reload was needed for changes to take effect

Answer (score 1):

Your queries seem to be correct. Were you able to solve this after reloading the collection?

After uploading the feature store to the `feature-store` and the `model` to the `model-store` it is important to reload the collection in order to successfully apply the changes. The same for the deletion.

If you are exploring the LTR part, [this blog post](https://sease.io/2021/03/common-errors-with-apache-solr-feature-stores-and-models.html) might come in handy.